# Why is 做 in the sentence 不知道大家觉得做女人最大的悲哀是什么？

Tags: grammar, word-choice, meaning-in-context

From a [MandarinCorner.org](http://mandarincorner.org/) video *I Hate Getting My Period* ([audio and transcript link](http://www.mandarincorner.org/pdfs-audio/); video is also searchable on YouTube), we have the following sentence:

> [image: 不知道大家觉得做女人最大的悲哀是什么？]
>
> Bù zhīdào dàjiā juédé zuò nǚrén zuìdà de bēi'āi shì shénme?
> 不知道大家觉得做女人最大的悲哀是什么？
> I don't know what you think is the difficult thing about being a woman?

I'm confused as to why 做 is in this sentence; it seems to serve some kind of grammatical function I'm not aware of.  It looks like it could be omitted without problem.  I also feel a bit of a mismatch between both 做 and 是 in the sentence.

**Question**: Why is 做 in the sentence 不知道大家觉得做女人最大的悲哀是什么？

Looking up 做 using the PeraPera Chinese Popup Dictionary:

> [image]
>
> to do; to make; to produce; to write; to compose; to act as; to engage in; to hold (a party); to be; to become; to function (in some capacity); to serve as; to be used for; to form (a bond or relationship); to pretend; to feign; to act a part; to put on appearance

Among many definitions, there's "to be", "to act as", and "to produce" on the list, which seem closest in meaning.  The 做 in the given sentence functions something like "is" (approximately "is the greatest annoyance"), which is typically performed by 是 (and this also occurs in the sentence).  However, we obviously can't just interchange 是 and 做 throughout Chinese.

I'm more familiar with using 做 to form a verb (e.g. 做饭 "cook food" and 做工业 "do homework") rather than in this case 做[悲哀](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E6%82%B2%E5%93%80) which seems along the lines of "give rise to annoyance".

Comment: being; acting as; playing the role of.

Comment: Did you consult any dictionaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

做 here is a verb, according to *Oxford*, meaning:

> 5 充当 be

they give three examples:

> 做个好孩子 
>   be a good child
>
> 做老实人 
>   be an honest person
>
> 做秘书 
>   be a secretary

Pleco's *PLC* dictionary also has this verbal meaning:

> 4 be; become
>
> 做演员 
>   zuò yǎnyuán
>   become an actor or actress; go on the stage
>
> 后来她做保育员了。 
>   Hòulái tā zuò bǎoyùyuán le.
>   Later she became a child-care worker.
>
> 今天开会由你做主席。 
>   Jīntiān kāihuì yóu nǐ zuò zhǔxí.
>   You’ll be the chairman at today’s meeting.

---

做女人 means, as the subtitles correctly translated above, to be a woman.

Answer (score 2):

做 is **being**.

是 is **to be**.

做女人 means **being a woman**.

是什麼 means **is what (what is)**.

You don't have to look at those 2 things together!

And if you omit the 做 in the sentence:

> 不知道大家觉得女人最大的悲哀是什么？

It becomes:

> I don't know (I wonder) what everybody think the biggest sorrow of a woman is?

As opposed to the original meaning

> I don't know (I wonder) what everybody think the biggest sorrow of **being** a woman is?

Can you see the subtle difference!?